# StreamReader with TcpClient returning incorrect strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, networking, stream, tcpclient

I am using TcpClient and NetworkStream to initiate a connection to a POP server for authentication. Bad practice, good for learning.

When I Telnet into the POP server, the response produced is initially :

```
+OK Dovecot Ready
```

User enters username

```
+OK
```

User enters pass which is checked
`+OK` if valid `-N` if not

My program is connecting to the POP server, opening a StreamReader and Writer, writing all of this data and checking the response.

```
   using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient("host.university.ie", 110)) {
        using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream()) {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream)) {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream)) {
            string response = reader.ReadLine();
            writer.Write("USER " + username );
            response = reader.ReadLine();
            writer.Write("PASS " + password );
            string response = reader.ReadLine();
            Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('The following response as been received: \n" + response + " .');</script>");
            isValid = response[ 0 ].Equals('+');
            writer.WriteLine("quit\n");
        }
       }
      }
     }
    }
```

However, when I enter this code, the query goes into an infinite loop. The confusing thing is that when I reduce the number of calls to reader.ReadLine() to one, it returns "+OK Dovecot Ready"! So it is connecting to the POP server but it will not work after this. Does anyone have any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Is "loops" the correct term to be using here? It's not clear from your code how looping could possibly occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't an infinite loop. The second call to `reader.ReadLine()` will never return, because you haven't finished sending the `USER` command to the server. You must send linefeed characters using `.WriteLine` instead of `.Write`

Try this:

```
writer.WriteLine("USER " + username);
writer.Flush();
```

and this:

```
writer.WriteLine("PASS " + password);
writer.Flush();
```

EDIT: Added calls to `.Flush` as per [spender](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14357/spender)'s suggestion.

Comment: I have tried this to no avail. I have changed .Write to .WriteLine and it still loops infinitely.

Comment: Try adding `.Flush()` after each call to `.WriteLine()`

Comment: Thank you! :) It is now working perfectly, will accept this answer in two minutes!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @atornblad's answer, consider `writer.Flush()` after you write to the stream and need a response.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check: CanWrite and CanRead on the stream and check your encoding:
See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.getstream.aspx

**Some further questions:**
Where is your infinity loop? I can not see any Loops in your code. ReadLine is a blocking method. Maybe the end of line character is the problem? Try Read() instead to get character wise output.

Where does it return "+OK Dovecot Ready"? If it is in your Gui try to call .Refresh on the element that should display the result because your GUI thread my be blocked by the following blocking ReadLine() calls.

Is this \n by purpose?

```
writer.WriteLine("quit\n");
```

This leads to an double Line termination.

And try to use

```
.Flush() after writing to your stream.
```

Comment: ReadLine is perfectly reasonable for communicating with a POP server. And it is the POP server that returns "+OK Dovecot Ready". This is obviously a web app, so there is no element to call .Refresh on, and no GUI thread.